# Как правильно сделать связь с таблицами SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Ребят подскажите, какие таблицы нужно сделать и какую связь, что бы реализовать след задачи.

Есть главная таблица где будут храниться медучереждения. Когда я добавлю медучереждение через админ панель я выбираю в какой категории он будет находиться. (больницы, скорая помощь, для детей). Но я могу могу выставить галочки что он будет находиться сразу в двух категориях. Как мне сделать что бы он в бд хранился в двух разных категориях? нужно добавлять в таблицу медучереждения два товара с разными категориями?

Comment: Три таблицы: 1. таблица медучереждений, 2. таблица категорий, 3. таблица связи с двумя полями в одном поле id медучереждения, во втором id категории. В 3й таблице на 1 медучереждение может быть несколько записей с разными категориями.

Comment: @Visman а добавлять данные в три таблицы поочереди? Сначала в Медучереждения. Получаю последний добавленный id. А потом в 3 таблицу добавляю id таблицы и id categotry

Comment: Да. Категории у вас заполнены. При заполнении нового медучереждения выбираете из списка категорий нужные. Сначала сохраняете данные в таблицу медучереждений и в ответ получаете id сохраненного медучереждения через функцию `mysqli_insert_id` например. Потом записываете выбранные id категорий(-ии) в третью таблицу вместе с id медучереждения..

Comment: @Visman  супер спасибо, еще вопрос, если я буду редактировать медучереждения, мне нужно из 3 таблицы удалять данные, и заново записывать с измененными категориями? Например было три категорию, одну я убрал, я удалил все данные из 3 таблицы, и записал обратно верно?

Comment: Можно для редактированного медучереждения удалить данные из 3 таблицы по его id и записать новые. А можно только разницу вносить, то есть если при редактировании учреждения категории для него не менялись, то и в 3й таблице ни каких изменений не делать и т.п.

Comment: Принимаю как правильный) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-й вариант это связующая таблица, 2-й вариант это поте типа текст в котором хранить json массив 
В твоем случае по моему массив проще будет, хотя не зная что там дальше будет происходить с БД тяжело сказать 
PS с массивом в запросе если вдруг понадобится пиши like '"22"', то есть ищи с кавычками если json  будешь хранить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]